# No entiendo porque no funciona el siguiente codigo en C

Tags: c

Estaba trabajando en c y viendo un manual antiguo me encontre con el siguiente código que parecía sencillo.

```
int num=50, i;
for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
{
    if( !( num % i)) //esta es la línea que saltea
    {
        printf(“%d”, i);
    }
}
```

Mi respuesta al compilar es que no muestran nada, no se si me faltará una porción de código pero en el manual dice que el if si tiene un valor distinto a cero por defecto entra en código y dicho valor en la condicion es el resto del numero dividido el contador negado. Quisiera saber qué resultado les da a ustedes cuando lo compilan y por qué yo no obtengo ningún dato al compilarlo (uso CODEBLOCKs).

Comment: Podrías explicar qué estás intentando hacer?

Comment: Compilo el siguiente codigo, dicho codigo decia que obtenia los primos del numero. Mi problema al compilar es que no aparece nada, no se si es problema del compilador y efectivamente el codigo es correcto o dicho codigo tiene algun error. Se de antemano que el if solo entra si es distinto a cero por consiguiente el contador "i" incializado en 1 deberia entrar en dicha condicion del if por que siempre va a ser un numero distinto a cero. Mi duda es ¿porque no me arroja ningun dato cuando lo compilo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema son las comillas y el "If".

Prueba esto:

```
int num=50, i;
for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
{
if( !( num % i)) //esta es la linea que saltea
{
printf("%d\n", i);
}
}
```

Por cierto, lo que se imprime no son los primos, son los números que dividen a num con resto 0.

Programa completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num=50, i;
for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
{
if( !( num % i)) //esta es la linea que saltea
{
printf("%d\n", i);
}
}
}
```